# Subtracting one column from another and display top 3 highest values of the subtracted values

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

x = df['gross'] - df.budget

y = x.groupby(x).nlargest(3)
```

I wanted to subtract the budget column from the gross column and display the top 3 highest values. But I'm not getting the top 3 subtracted highest values and I'm stuck on how to proceed. I need some assistance.

Answer (score 4):

## Updated:

I don't think you need `groupby` here, you can simply use:

`(df['gross'] - df['budget']).nlargest(3)`

Other way if you would like to maintain difference in separate column, then is to create next column to keep the difference between `gross` and `budget`, sort by values of it and get `top` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gross':[10,20,30,40,50], 'budget':[8,15,10,10,10]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     budget  gross
0       8     10
1      15     20
2      10     30
3      10     40
4      10     50
```

Now, creating column to keep `difference`:

```
df['difference'] = df['gross'] - df.budget
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     budget  gross  difference
0       8     10           2
1      15     20           5
2      10     30          20
3      10     40          30
4      10     50          40
```

Now, sorting by difference in `descending` and getting top values:

```
top_3 = df.sort_values(by='difference', ascending=False)[:3]
print(top_3)
```

Output:

```
     budget  gross  difference
4      10     50          40
3      10     40          30
2      10     30          20
```